# use gdal to create a vector layer mask of a raster file

Tags: python, border, mask, gdal, qgis

I need to programatically generate a shapefile of a raster images border using gdal. 
I'll then use this shapefile to clip and blend the edges of the image and other gdal magic. 
I'm having trouble finding the proper gdal tool to generate the vector mask.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`gdaltindex`](http://www.gdal.org/gdaltindex.html). Input a raster, specify output OGR format and file.